# umbraco 6 home errors out on appharbor

Tags: umbraco, nullreferenceexception, appharbor

Here's the scoop. I created an Umbraco 6 MVC app locally (pointing to a Yocto shared SQL server appharbor add-on), installed it and it runs fine. I can add doc types, create content, blah, blah.... locally.

Then I pushed the solution to the AppHarbor GIT repo and it built and deployed successfully. However, to my surprise, I get a lovely YSOD and the following error when I try to go to the home page:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule.BeginRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) +13    Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule.b__5(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +253
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +136    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

The app's errors logs report this error is occurring for the following request paths:
/
/favicon.ico

This one has me stumped. Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems like there's some related discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369301/app-code-folder-created-automatically-in-published-website

Comment: I did see the post you mentioned, but it didn't help me resolve my issue.

Comment: Can you browse to favicon.ico in your repo? Try clicking on the file in your solution and setting to Copy Always, recommit and publish.

Comment: @MikeW thank you for the feedback. I will try what you suggest the next time I'm in front of VS.

Comment: Any news on this?
I'm not using apphabour, but I have the same error, when I deploy to IIS7.

Answer (score 1):

Answer was right above this one on google. :)
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/37908-Error-while-setting-up-U6RC-site-from-Visual-Studio-

You're probably missing global.asax. I created an empty ASP.NET project, and Umbraco nuget package didn't include global.asax in content / project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the a similar error with Umbraco 7 installed with package-manager.

The fix was to edit the global.asax from

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

to

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication" Language="C#" %>
```